# How can I tell what part of the model the UV map is from? (In Blender)

Tags: uv

I have a model in blender, and when I unwrap it, I noticed that there is a lot of stretch in one section.  How can I tell what section of the model this is from?

[image: Blender visual of unwrapped model]

As you can see, there is one Huge green area that shows a many more vertex's than I was expecting to see.

Also, those boxes look huge.  Is everything the same scale?

Comment: It may be useful to see the 3D mesh and the UV at the same time as indicated in the answer below.  How was texture created?  Texture painting?  Since the UV can be edited this is one way the faces could seem incorrect to you.  If this is a learning experience you may want to have more space between the UV islands.  Strive to create a UV Map where no faces overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UV Face Identification and Coordination**

[image]

[image]

Image above.  Open two windows. One with the mesh in [edit mode]. We assume one UV. One with the UV image editor with the texture selected.  If you select faces of the mesh model you will see them highlighted in the UV editor window with the default settings.  You can change the setting indicated by the yellow arrow are to keep the Selection in Sync.  You may select faces in either the UV Image Editor or The 3D View Window with mesh in edit mode.

Notice the face selection mode.  The red seam allows the blender user to move the islands.

**Face Size**

Relative Face size in the UV Map and face size of the mesh model can be different and this is a flexible feature. Same scale is not necessary. We might imagine we want more detail in the face of some character than we want on the bottom of the foot.

**Changing Island Size**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I understand why they might be different.  But I do have some faces that are scaled differently (and so the texture is showing up different) but should really look the same, is there a way to make it scale the same?  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please see above.  There are some videos at some [famous] video site about UV mapping in detail.  I think a video may provide more general explanations and well worth 30 minutes.  Search ... Blender UV Mapping ....

Comment: Lastly anyone can have an unwanted UV unwrap. Blender has two meanings to uv unwrap.  Blender has uv unwrap user actions and uv unwrap denotes the final data stored in the file.   Blender allows one face at a time to be unwrapped as an action, updating the final piece of data representing the uv unwrap when the file is saved. This may seem not useful to some people.  So this is another source of potential error.  I might also suggest delete the UV unwrap and create a new one. UV Unwraps come and go and are meant to deleted and created again.  A New uv unwrap may give you a fresh start.

Comment: UV editor menu > uvs > average island scale. This would scale your uv to the match them relative to the scale of your meshes. Shortcut is Ctrl + A.

Comment: @hawkenfox  the concept of average scale island was in the answer prior to your comment. 10 hours ago. You appear to be repeating the information in the answer.