# How do I add more than 8 decals to an object?

Tags: uv, node-editor

I'm trying to add multiple decals to an object. For example a race car with all the sponsorship logos. The method I tried restricts the number of decals to the number of UV maps that I can create in blender which is 8.

This is the link to how the nodes are setup.He sets up the nodes at roughly 10-12 minutes in.

https://vimeo.com/36632196

So is there a better method of doing it where i can use more than 8 decals?

Comment: A single texture can hold multiple visual decals.  Portions of a mesh can be targeted for areas of the texture via the UV Map.  So 88 logos can be in one texture if you have the patience.  You may be able to place all logos with one texture if done properly.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45638/how-do-i-put-a-stencil-like-texture-across-a-sectioned-object/45639#45639     https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46403/uvmap-spills-over-onto-unselected-areas/46408#46408

Comment: Suggested Tutorial if that suits you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tovu1A0LxeQ  .  Suggestion see 3 other tutorials.  The tutorial you referenced maybe showing possibilities that are not suited to your current needs.  For example file formats which can hold transparency information such as PNG or OpenEXR do NOT need two files.

Comment: Please show your work with two logos in one texture and you will see how UV Maps can target two different areas of the texture.

Comment: If you have two separate logos as files you can use GIMP or Blender to combine them into one PNG or OpenEXR with transparency.  GIMP is free.  These comments are not meant to be tutorials.

Comment: Blender Render or Cycles Render for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Render]

Image above.  Rendered image with two imagined logos on particular faces.

[image: UV Map]
Image above.  UV Maps.  Color Blue used to increase visibility of Seams.

Mapping Extension set to Clip.
Even if you see Blender Render the UV Map applies to Cycles Render as well. Combined with the video tutorials you have seen you can do this. Note the part of UV is off the image which is what I want.  The Clip setting allows us to exclude modifications of color from parts of the mesh.  Please click to see larger image.

What is presented here is a quick summary, not a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, I know what I'm doing wrong now. So basically I have to create one texture with all the decals layered into it in the shape of my UV map. What resolution should I be using for the texture?

Comment: Use what best fits your circumstance.  If you use 4 textures that might be reasonable with some questionable logic that 2 * 2 = 4 and you know how to place 4 images if they need to be combined in that situation.  LOD level of detail matters.  If you expect some logo to be the center of attention it should occupy enough or more space in the texture.  You should start with 2 or more logos in the texture to start your experience.